# Is there a way to maximise the current tab in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ide, fullscreen

I sometimes need to use Visual Studio when I have limited screen real estate (remote desktopping from a laptop for example).  **It would be really useful to be able to make the currently selected code tab maximise to take the whole screen for a limited time.**

Is that possible?  Is there a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

View->Full Screen   (Shift + Alt + Enter)

Does that work?

Comment: holy crap, this is the best thing ever.

Comment: I can't believe people are not familiar with this, but every time I work with other devs, they are amazed by it or, more amazing, hate it. Show me the code!

Comment: This is not working for me

Answer (score 3):

I use Shift-Alt-Enter to activate full screen mode.